# Mssql: how can I create a table with 2 variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create table dbo.abc
As
Declare @start as date=convert(varchar(10),getdate()-7,111)
Declare @end as date=convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,111)
Select bla from blabla where blablabla between @start and @end
```

It returns error and not allow to declare variables when creating table, how to solve it?

Thanks for your attention. Hope it's clear enough

Kind regards,
Lawrence

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for a view rather than a table? (Do you expect the contents of this table to be fixed when you run this script or to vary as the date moves forward?)

Comment: A table just contains data. Do you maybe want a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax makes no sense.  If you want to create a table in SQL Server, then use `select . . . into`:

```
Declare @start date = cast(getdate() - 7 as date);
Declare @end date = cast(getdate() - 1 as date);

Select bla
into dbo.abc
from blabla 
where blablabla between @start and @end;
```

Note that there is no reason to convert to strings in order to remove the time component.

Comment: If insert "into" to create that table, can every single time to query the table by those declare variables?

Comment: @YungLinMa . . . `select . . . into` is the equivalent of `create table as` in other databases.  Neither allow you to append data on an existing table.  Hence, this answers your question.  If you want to add data to a table, then you want to use `insert`.

Comment: Sorry my bad english. I dont mean to insert any new data to the table(IT department will do it). I just want to create a table which can steadily to fetch pass 7 days data

Comment: Can this "into" method goes according to those 2 variable?

Comment: @YungLinMa It will create your table. Select...into creates your table for you.

Comment: Static table or dynamic table?

Comment: @YungLinMa . . . What is a dynamic table?

Comment: Yesterday I created the table, the date within the table is between 13 to 19 April , and I call this table today, I find it is the same date like yesterday, I want it to get the variables that I set to get date between 14 to 20 April

Comment: @YungLinMa . . . Use a calendar table and a `where` clause.

Comment: For user use only, how can I create a table with where clause?

Comment: The user dont know how to set the dates, So I want to set the date variables inside the table